# Issue with cacheHtml settings

Tags: caching

Recently, we have enabled "cacheHtml" in the Site Config file for our PREPROD/PROD site as true. After that, we have noticed that a specific component on a page is getting cached, although cache is not enabled for that component or the page. We are not able to understand the root cause of this behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange! Please could you check a few things and add these details to the question? 1. What are the values of response HTTP headers `Cache-Control` and `Pragma` for this page? This is needed just to exclude browser caching the entire page. 2. Is there another wrapper/parent component that could be cached with your component inside it? 3. Does your component cache get refreshed on publish?

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is only with one specific component and all other components show the updates on page refresh? If not, most likely your page is cached.  You can verify this by opening the page in different browser on different machines. If the page is cached in Sitecore, you can clear Sitecore by going to sitecore/admin/cache.aspx page. You can also try republishing the page which should refresh Sitecore cache. You can always revert the setting back to check if the setting is the root cause for the issue.